# unable to create databases via console with XAMPP installed

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on macOS with m1 chipset, and I am unable to run it through console, I have read several articles but all I was able to accomplish is that when I type source ~/.bash_profile I get /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php instead of /usr/bin/php but when I type mysql -p root -u and then show databases it does not show me preinstalled by XAMPP databases and on window it did, like the path was leading to some other directory than the one with the app installed but it kind of shows corect one, could you please advise me on that? This is my ~/.bash_profile

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: macOS has not used bash for a couple of years now. You will need to edit the `.zshrc` file if you would like to modify the path.

Comment: ha! :D thank you so so much!